# Possible to do with Awk or Sed? Splitting big file into smaller files. Lines between two markers

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Is it possible to do something like this with `awk` or `sed`? ...or will I have to use `perl` or `python` (or I guess C++, since that's what I'm most comfortable in)?

Lets say I have a file with a list of items in categories and sub-categories:

```
* Birds
  - Sparrow
  - Magpie
  - Crow
  - Parrot
* Mammals
  * Pets
    - Dog
    - Cat
    - Rabbit
  * Pests
    - Trash-panda
    - Skunk
* Fish
  - Trout
  - Herring
  - Salmon
(...)
```

This should be split into three files - Birds, Mammals and Fish (don't need to split-up the two sub-categories under Mammals) - containing what's between one category and the next (or end-of-file).  An alternative may be to output from first category/start-of-file to second category to a file, and then automatically/manually remove this from the original file before repeating...

Basically, what I'd like to know, is how to make `awk` or `sed` output what's between two markers (here between two `*`).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `*` is the first character of the category lines, then

```
$ awk '/^\*/{close(f); f=$2; next} f{print > f}' file

$ head Birds Mammals Fish
==> Birds <==
  - Sparrow
  - Magpie
  - Crow
  - Parrot

==> Mammals <==
  * Pets
    - Dog
    - Cat
    - Rabbit
  * Pests
    - Trash-panda
    - Skunk

==> Fish <==
  - Trout
  - Herring
  - Salmon
```

Comment: This is excellent - I wonder if you could provide a brief explanation. In particuar, I'm unclear on why you `close(f)` first, and use `/^` in the match test - is this an anchor?

Comment: @Seamus the idea is to `close` the *previous* file each time - the first time through, `f` is empty and the `close` is a no-op. It's debatable whether managing the number of open filehandles in this way is strictly necessary, but it doesn't add much overhead. Yes `^` is an anchor - without it, `/\*/` would match sub-categories as well.

Answer (score 0):

The csplit utility is meant for splitting files based on contexts such as in this case.

```
csplit -sz yourfile '/^[*]/' '{*}'
for f in xx*
do {
  dst=$(head -n 1 -|cut -d' ' -f2)
  cat - > "$dst"
} < "$f"
done
head Birds Fish Mammals
```

```
==> Birds <==
  - Sparrow
  - Magpie
  - Crow
  - Parrot

==> Fish <==
  - Trout
  - Herring
  - Salmon

==> Mammals <==
  * Pets
    - Dog
    - Cat
    - Rabbit
  * Pests
    - Trash-panda
    - Skunk
```